# count number of letters that occur in a string and add the letter and number of times it occurs to a dictionary as a key value pair

Tags: python, dictionary

I have written a function to count the number of times a letter occurs in a string and return the letter and the number of times it appears in the string as key: value pairs inside a dictionary, the function is to ignore any punctuation.

here is what I have

```
def count_letters(text):
    result = {}
    for letter in text:
        if letter.isalpha():
            if result[letter.lower()]:
                result[letter.lower()] += 1
            result[letter.lower()] = 1
    return(result)
```

I thought if the key result[letter] doesn't exist it should skip the if statement

```
if result[letter.lower()]:
```

but instead it throws a key error, what am I doing wrong?

I am expecting if

```
text = "This is a sentence."
```

then my function should return

```
{'t': 2, 'h': 1, 'i': 2, 's': 3, 'a': 1, 'e': 3, 'n': 2, 'c': 1}
```

I am trying to do this without importing any modules, its a learning exercise to improve my knowledge of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
def count_letters(text):
    result = {}
    for letter in text:
        if letter.isalpha():
            if letter.lower() in result.keys():
                result[letter.lower()] += 1
            else:
                result[letter.lower()] = 1
    return(result)
```

Comment: I tried exactly this except I used if letter.lower() in result.items():

Now I know where I went wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's throwing a keyerror because that key doesn't exist yet. Use a try-except instead:

```
lower = letter.lower()  # Only need to do this once
try:
    result[lower] += 1
except KeyError:
    result[lower] = 1
```

Also FWIW, the canonical way to do this is with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), e.g:

```
collections.Counter(c.lower() for c in text if c.isalpha())
```

Comment: Thanks! Word as expected, I saw a lot of articles showing I could get the same answer using collections.Counter but this was a learning exercise for using dictionaries.

Appreciate both answers!